# MySQL column name selection

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column name 'Segment Type', but when i use SELECT Segment Type FROM results; it gives me error (unknown column 'Segment' in field list).

But this code works if it written Segment_type with the underscore. So how to i select a column name that does not have a underscore?

I tried using multiple ways of selecting but because there is no underscore in the column name i cant select it.

Comment: Review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html#:~:text=Certain%20objects%20within%20MySQL%2C%20including,syntax%20for%20identifiers%20in%20MySQL.

Comment: Your title says "MySQL" so why have you tagged [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:sqlite]] as well? What do *all three* products have to do with what you are asking? How does Python become involved?

Comment: Use underscore in the column name, to avoid future problems.

Comment: Avoid using spaces in column names.

Comment: you need to use Backtick -  SELECT ` Segment Type ` FROM results (remove spaces from before and after, I just added to make it visible and not allow SO to treat it as code

Answer (score -3):

Use double quotes around the column names.

```
select "Segment Type" from
```

MySQL will parse the contents of the double quotes as a string literal.

Comment: This only replaces all the info in the row as Segment Type, it doesnt grab the info in Segment type.

Comment: Ah my bad, I just checked and I'm wrong. It's a SQL dialect thing. In Postgres what I said is correct. In MYSQL one uses backticks `\``